# how to convert json(list) to java class

Tags: json, spring, retrofit

i used Spring boot, retofit
i want to get response to user class

response from server is here

```
{
    "userid": "jin",
    "sex": true,
    "height": 180,
    "authorityDtoSet": [
        {
            "authorityName": "ROLE_USER"
        }
    ]
}
```

i don't know how to conver authorityName to java class
and get response

android code here

```
public class RetrofitClient {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    public RetrofitService retrofitService = retrofit.create(RetrofitService.class);
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RetrofitClient retrofitClient = new RetrofitClient();
        Call<User> call = retrofitClient.retrofitService.getProduct3("jin", "Token");

        call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    Log.i("Tag", "Success : " + response.toString());
                    Log.i("Tag", "Success : " + response.body().toString());
                } else {
                    Log.i("Tag", "Failed");
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Tag", "Failed" + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

public interface RetrofitService {
    @GET("user/{userid}")
    Call<User> getProduct3(@Path("userid") String userid, @Header("Authorization") String token);
}
```

android user class

```
public class User {
    @SerializedName("userid")
    private String userid;
    @SerializedName("sex")
    private boolean sex;
    @SerializedName("height")
    private int height;
    @SerializedName("authorityDtoSet")
    private List<AuthorityDto> authorityDtoSet;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PostResult{" +
                "userid=" + userid +
                ", sex=" + sex +
                ", height='" + height + '\'' +
                ", authorityDtoSet='" + authorityDtoSet + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

public class AuthorityDto {
    AuthorityDto(){}
    private String authorityName;
}
```

i think User class(android) doesn't match response(Server)
so i can't get data
how can i get json list data from server?
plz help

Comment: Do you have getters and setters on `User` and `AuthorityDto` ?

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with the DTO structure itself. It seems to be correct. 
If you want to verify it for yourself, use online converters such as:  https://json2csharp.com/json-to-pojo